# Invalid binding path 'nn.aa' : Property 'n' can't be found on type 'cc'

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, uwp-xaml, windows-10-iot-core

today I just found a Visual Studio 2017 Bug while playing an UWP Project. wanna report here. I just lose a day and hope this will be a timesaver who will face same problem.

error was an XAML error relevant to x:Bind / x:DataType

**Invalid binding path 'nöbetci.AdSoyad' : Property 'n' can't be found on type 'MdYrdNobetGunu''**

```
    <ListView x:Name="listViewNobMudYrdCalendar">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="Models:MdYrdNobetGunu">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind nöbetçi.AdSoyad}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

after losing a day,Finally just renamed a non-ascii (unicode) Model class property name to ascii standards fixed problem (ö>o and ç>c). Im sure because reverted code back causes always same error. doesn't compile. compiler throws same error. it seems a VS bug. Weird but real.

```
   public class MdYrdNobetGunu
        {
            //singleton
            public static ObservableCollection<MdYrdNobetGunu> NöbetGünleri = new ObservableCollection<MdYrdNobetGunu>();

            //public NobMdYrd nöbetçi { get; set; }//raises a xaml relevant bug
            public NobMdYrd nobetci { get; set; } //works
            .......
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your sharing, Kursat. I have tested the code you provided, but did not encounter the issue.Which version is your vs2017? My is vs2017 15.4.5.
[image]

Comment: 15.4.5 Community Ed  I think. Let me simplify  app and share here late of the day.